# Custom formating in full description from msteams' manifest

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to use some custom formatting in msteams' full description e.g. new lines?
I've tried to do it (to add two new lines between some portions of text) in App Studio (`Descriptions` section, `Full description` field), but during the instalation process I see only one line in description (rest of new lines is omitted).

[image]

What is iteresting in manifest json file I see `\n\n` so description should show two new lines.
Situation is even worse in `About` tab. All formating is not interpreted there.

[image]

UPDATE:
Manifest (sensitive data has been replaced by `XXX`):

`{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.16",
    "id": "XXX",
    "packageName": "XXX",
    "developer": {
        "name": "XXX",
        "websiteUrl": "XXX",
        "privacyUrl": "XXX",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "XXX"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "XXX",
        "full": "XXX"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "XXX",
        "full": "**Lorem Ipsum** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  \nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n- It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.  \nIt was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    },
    "accentColor": "XXX",
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "XXX",
            "name": "XXX",
            "contentUrl": "XXX",
            "websiteUrl": "XXX",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "XXX"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "XXX",
        "resource": "XXX"
    }
}`

Comment: Please look at [long description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/detail-page-checklist#long-description) markdown supporting.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Markdown does work on installation screen (my first screenshot). In `About` page  markdown is unfortunately not interpreted and description still looks like on my second screenshot. Is that intentional behaviour or bug?

Comment: Could you please provide us your manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I've added it to question (it was too long to leave it in comments)

Comment: We have filed a Bug for this. We will let you know once we got any update

Comment: The fix has been deployed You can check it now